# Theme.Dialog doesnt show what I wanted to

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am just trying to write a MenuInflate. when user clicks to AboutUs button a small dialog box should appear and write what I want to. But somehow it writes MainActivity instead of "About us About us"

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.aboutUs:
                Intent i = new Intent("com.android.ABOUT");
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.preferences:
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

this is my about.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About me About Me" >
        </TextView>
    >

    </LinearLayout>
```

and related part of AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".AboutUs"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.ABOUT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

[image: and screenshot]

Comment: What does your `AboutActivity` look like? Specifically the `onCreate()`

Comment: @codeMagic oh I commented out setContentView(R.layout.about); because of that it didnt work.thank you for reminding me that :p

Comment: You're welcome. That's what I assumed happened :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout_file)` isn't included in the `onCreate()` method then Android doesn't know what `View` to display resulting in nothing to display in the `Activity`. This also will keep the `Activity` from being able to instantiate any `Views` such as `TextViews`, `EditText`s, `Buttons`, etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)